# getElementID dont work on chrome

Tags: javascript

I have a code like this:

```
parent.document.getElementById("test").value ="1";
```

but it doesnt work on chrome. The error is:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call
>   method 'getElementById' of undefined"

any help is apreciated thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Omit the `parent.` part.

Comment: @BeemerGuy: why didn't you answer that?

Comment: @Chris -- I wasn't sure if it was the correct answer =/

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("test").value ="1";
```

parent of the scope (window) is null

Comment: Actually one can deduce from the error message that parent is not null. ;)

Comment: To be pedantic, I think parent.document is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is strange. Because your code should work. I even tested it now to be sure. So somehow your `parent` isn't the `window` object. That's why it has no `document` property.

The global `parent` is the parent property of the `window` object (`window.parent`) which usually points to the `window` object itself . So usually `parent` and `window` are the same thing and you don't even have to use this object explicitly most of the time.

So my guess is that you've somehow overwritten `parent` with some other object.

Edit: My second guess is that you haven't overwritten parent yourself but have embedded the window into another window. So your parent becomes this outer window and you probably don't have access to its document.